# Phone call in Phonegap on Blackberry

Tags: cordova, blackberry-10, tel

Phone links like `<a href="tel:1-408-555-5555">1-408-555-5555</a>` are used in my app. On Blackberry 10 device, they work fine in browser. But when I wrap my app into Phonegap, the doesn't, just nothing happens. How do I dial a phone number from a phonegap app on Blackberry? My device is Blackberry Z10, if this matters.

**Edit:**
Actually I've missed from my code that links have empty href href="#" and then phone dial fires from javascript. I've changed this to direct links and dial works.

Comment: take off the dashes maybe, otherwise, it look ok.

Answer (score 1):

you can also create a function like this.  worst case.

```
function callSomeone(number){
    if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/android/)) {
        document.location.href = 'tel:'+number;
    } else if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/iphone/) || navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/ipad/)) {
        window.plugins.phoneDialer.dial(number);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is for ios, actually sorry, https://github.com/j-mcnally/PhoneGap-ios-PhoneDialer

Comment: Thank you @kangoroo. Actually I've missed from my code that links have empty href `href="#"` and then phone dial fires from javascript. I've changed this to direct links as in my question and dial works. Sorry for interruption, it was hard day, and thank you for your attention.